# Drawing on canvas with React setState

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, canvas

My issue, i'm trying to draw on to canvas array of images with React setState, derived from links. After some manipulations with canvas i rerendering everything, It works, but i encounter minor inconsistency. I need to "play" with canvas for quite 10 minutes to let this bug occur.

**Should be:**[image: All images mapped once]

**What occasionally happens:**
[image]

I've tried everything i can, i'm sure i'm drawing them only once. I've tried to call it from setState callback, from setTimeout it setState callback, from setTimeout separately etc, all the time bug still persist. I'm aware about asynchronous nature of setState, but this should be working fine. It's hard for me to understand is this related to canvas api or react api. If you need additional info let me know! Relevant code:

```
export let mapImage=curry((
    ctx:CanvasRenderingContext2D,
    link:string,
    width:number,
    location:Vertex
)=>{
    let img=new Image();
    let place=location; 
    img.src=link;    
    img.onload=()=>{ 
        ctx.save(); 
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(
            place.x+width/2,
            place.y+width/2,
            width/2,
            0,
            Math.PI*2,true
        );  
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.clip();
        ctx.drawImage( 
            img,  
            place.x,
            place.y,
            width,   
            width  
        );         
        ctx.restore();   
    };  
});       

On event:
       this.setState({down_delay:0, 
                      mouse_down:false},()=>{this.drawCard()}); 

In drawCard:
       this.context.clearRect(0,0,this.props.width,this.props.height);
       map(mapImage,this.props.vertices) 

...rest of the code
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not possible to give a perfect answer based on the information provided. That said most commonly I find people do:

```
   this.setState({down_delay:0, 
                  mouse_down:false},()=>{this.drawCard()}); 
   moreCodeWithoutRealizingItWillRunBeforeDrawCard();
```

## Suggested exploration

You cn avoid a number of these issues by using `@action` decorators and mobx. [I stopped using setState](https://medium.com/@mweststrate/3-reasons-why-i-stopped-using-react-setstate-ab73fc67a42e)